# How to rebase a chunk of commit onto another commit?

Tags: git, rebase

I have a very ugly situation in Git where in my `devel` branch I have

```
* deadbeef 1 hour ago (devel)
|
* ... (a bunch of commits)
|
* d5fca6e 11 days ago
*   8ca4341 11 days ago   Merge branch 
|\
| *   844d521 11 days ago    Merge Branch
| |\
| * | bdded77 11 days ago  
* | | 514e1e3 11 days ago  
* | | 61c8a0a 11 days ago  
* | | 1a155e8 11 days ago  
| |/
|/|
* | 19eeb57 11 days ago 
* | 0f6e367 11 days ago 
|/
* bb1ca0d 11 days ago
```

I would like to get

```
* bdded77' 11 days ago  
* 514e1e3' 11 days ago  
* 61c8a0a' 11 days ago  
* 1a155e8' 11 days ago  
* 19eeb57' 11 days ago 
* 0f6e367' 11 days ago 
* bb1ca0d 11 days ago
```

I tried to simply `cherry-pick` the commits in order to linearize the changes:

```
git checkout bb1ca0d
git cherry-pick 0f6e367 
git cherry-pick 19eeb57 
git cherry-pick 1a155e8
git cherry-pick 61c8a0a
git cherry-pick 514e1e3
git cherry-pick bdded77
```

After that I needed to *rebase* the rest on the top of it. What I tried is

```
git cherry-pick d5fca6e..devel
```

I get a lot of conflicts, so perhaps this cherry-pick does not work like this. But: `git diff bdded77 HEAD` does not show me anything.

How should I deal with this?

**EDIT**

I found my mistake with the last cherry-pick. I should have written:

```
git cherry-pick d5fca6e^..deadbeef
```

The initial question remains, is there a better solution?

Comment: Doing a rebase over a bunch of merge commits may be fraught with problems.  You may have to redo all the merge commits.

Comment: _I would like to get_ - but why? Because it looks nicer, or for some functional reason? You could just omit the `--graph` from `git log --graph` if you don't want to see it.

Comment: @Useless, it is just for readability. I like to `push` nice and clean history for the one who wants to dig into previous changes. The example here is clearly something that happens when someone do a merge after a rebase.

Comment: In that case, if you think the graph is hard (or ugly) to read, just don't read it. A flat `git log` will already linearize this for you, so you're going out of your way to display information you neither want nor need.

Comment: It sounds like, if I don’t like to do the dishes, I just don’t need to... in my opinion SCM history is part of the documentation and it should be always neat, clean and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is fine, but the `cherry-pick` must use a range of commit that include the first parent of your current `HEAD`.

```
*   (c)
*   (b)
*   (a)
| * (a', HEAD)
|/
*
```

Here you should write:

```
git cherry-pick b^..c
```

Where `b^` refers to `a` then the range of commit you have is:

```
a^..c === b, c
```

After this operation you will get:

```
* (c)
* (b)
* (a)
| * (c', HEAD)
| * (b')
| * (a')
|/
*
```